# Creating an MVC Controller Proxy for a Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, proxy

I have an MVC project that is exposed externally.  I have an internal Web API project.

For reasons beyond my control, I cannot expose the Web API project directly and I cannot add Web API Controllers to my MVC project.

I need to create an MVC Controller that will act as a proxy for a Web API Controller.  I need the response from the MVC Controller to look as if the Web API was called directly.

**What is the best way to accomplish this?**

**Is there a better approach than what I have so far?**

**How can I fix the error that I am getting?**

Here is what I have so far:

**MyMVCController**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        ...

        var response = proxy.GetData();

        return request.CreateResponse();
    }
```

**MyProxyClass**

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
    {
        ...
        return HttpRequest(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri));
    }

private HttpResponseMessage HttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        ...

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            response = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

In the MVC Controller, I am getting an InvalidOperationException on the request.CreateResponse() line.  The error says:

> The request does not have an associated configuration object or the provided configuration was null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched Google and StackOverflow but I haven't been able to find a good solution for creating this proxy between MVC and Web API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by just creating some `JsonResult` action in your controller which will return result of calling web API.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> CallToWebApi()
    {
        return this.Content(
            await new WebApiCaller().GetObjectsAsync(),
            "application/json"
        );
    }
}

public class WebApiCaller
{
    readonly string uri = "your url";

    public async Task<string> GetObjectsAsync()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that always return a 200 status code? I need to preserve whatever status code of the response from the Web API.  Also, I don't want the Web API to serialize the object, the proxy de-serialize it, and then the MVC serialize the object again.

Comment: you could always return status code you want base on result you achieve from web api call

Comment: what about the serialize, de-serialize, serialize again issue?

Comment: Also, what would happen if the Web Api returned an error message/response. The WebApiCaller would try to deserialize it into the expected object type which would then throw an error right?

Comment: modified. Withou deserialization. For details look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9777889/1235390