# Sending JSON response via GenericJsonWebHookReceiver MVC ASP.NET

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I need to send the JSON response from GenericJsonWebHookReceiver provided by Nuget package in ASP.NET.
I am trying to send the JSON value in the return call like this - "return Task.FromResult(sampleJson);"  , where sampleJson is a valid JSON in string format.
But while testing, I am still getting empty response.

How can we send the JSON response with GenericJsonWebHookReceiver? Also how to set the proper header type in the response to define it as JSON type response?

Thanks,
/vikas

Comment: Can you post your action method were you are setting the response from GenericJsonWebHookReceiver? Most likely this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777731/mvc-how-to-return-a-string-as-json

Comment: `        public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
        {
            // Get data from WebHook
            CustomNotifications data = context.GetDataOrDefault<CustomNotifications>();
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> notification in data.Notifications)
            {
                // Process data
            }

         
            // Get data from each notification in this WebHook
            JObject JO = new JObject();
            
         
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }`