# Change content-type of a Response from "text/html" to "application/json"

Tags: c#, .net, response, content-type

i  have my string text in my variable in C#:

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
return readText;
```

When i call this from my FE, the response type is text/html.

[image]

How can i change it in "application/json"? Is there any ChangeResponseType method for a string variable?

Comment: If you are using asp.net core add this attribute  `[Produces("application/json")]` to your action method

Comment: If using asp.net core you could also use this for returning `return this.Content(readText, "application/json");`. Got the information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777731/mvc-how-to-return-a-string-as-json)